# How to trigger event on closing of a tab in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to call a function in angularJs everytime when I close the tab of browser.
For this I have written this code:

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    $scope.clientLogout('login');
};
```

$scope.clientLogout() is defined in the parent controller.
Now when I close the tab from the parent controller, its working fine but its not able to call $scope.clientLogout() function when in child Controller.

I have also tried the below code and its working fine:

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return ('hi');
};
```

Can anyone explain me?

Comment: `onbeforeunload` is not reliable, it executes whatever it has time to execute before the browser closes, but it doesn't stop the browser from closing a tab, for obvious reasons (spam), so you'll never know if there was time enough to log out the client or not.

Comment: Can u  tell me what should I use in this case??